# Testing primes in Java - adding additional conditions

Tags: java

Beginner here. So I want to write a program that prints out all the prime numbers up to the number the user entered. E.g., user enters 5, program prints out 2 and 3. That part I understand, however what I am struggling with, is what if I want the program to print out whether the number the user entered is a prime or not (simple yes or no) IF the entered number is bigger than, let's say, 50. Here is code for first part:

```
public class Primes {      

  public static void main(String args[]) {    

    System.out.println("All primes up to: ");  

    int num = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();  

    System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to " + num + " are: ");  

    for(int number = 2; number<=num; number++){  
        if(isPrime(number)){  
            System.out.println(number);  
        }   
     }  

  }  

  public static boolean isPrime(int number){  
      for(int i=2; i<number; i++){  
         if(number%i == 0){  
             return false;   
         }  
      }  
    return true;   
  }  
}
```

I honestly can't wrap my around as to what I should be doing next. My first program ever (`"Hello world"` does not count ;P).

Comment: You need an `if` statement to check if the number is bigger than 50... What have you tried?

Comment: if(isPrime(number) && number > 50){...}

Comment: Also, in your `isPrime()` method, you only need to check up to number/2 in your `for` loop. Numbers bigger than half of your inputted number will never be a factor.

Comment: I tried adding if, but it did not work because I dont know where exactly to put it.

Comment: Also, a couple tips: start number at 3 and increment by 2 (since all evens will not be prime), and when you are checking if a number is prime, you only need to iterate up to the square root of the number, since factors of a number are mirrored around the square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit :**

**Your current code seems to work fine.**

As per your doubt as mentioned in one of the comments : `Yes, but where do I add if statement that does the following: if the number entered is below 50, then the program prints out all the prime numbers up to the entered number. If the number the user entered is bigger than 50, it tells only whether the entered number is prime or not ( simply "It's a prime" or "No, it's not a prime"). Hope that made things clearer`

The check you need to put is after you take the input :

```
int num = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();  

if( number > 50 )
{
    if(isPrime(number))
    {
       // print out is prime
    }
    // print out it is not prime
}

else
{
    System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to " + num + " are: ");  

    for(int number = 2; number<=num; number++){  
       if(isPrime(number)){  
            System.out.println(number);  
        }   
    }
 }
```

**SUGESTIONS :**

However, just to touch upon the algorithmic part, I would recommend using `Sieve of Eratosthenes` for picking out all the prime numbers within a given range, as you need in your case.

**Example :**

To find all the prime numbers less than or equal to 30, proceed as follows:

First generate a list of integers from 2 to 30:

```
2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

Strike (sift out) the multiples of 2 resulting in:

```
2  3     5     7     9    11    13    15    17    19    21    23    25    27    29
```

The first number in the list after 2 is 3; strike the multiples of 3 from the list to get:

```
2  3     5     7          11    13          17    19          23    25          29
```

The first number in the list after 3 is 5; strike the remaining multiples of 5 from the list:

```
2  3     5     7          11    13          17    19          23                29
```

The first number in the list after 5 is 7, but 7 squared is 49 which is greater than 30 so the process is finished. The final list consists of all the prime numbers less than or equal to 30.

Here's the code attached for reference ( Disclaimer : I'm picking up this code here from [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/14array/PrimeSieve.java.html) site. Just pasted it here for more immediate visibility).

**Code :**

```
public class PrimeSieve {
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    // initially assume all integers are prime
    boolean[] isPrime = new boolean[N + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        isPrime[i] = true;
    }

    // mark non-primes <= N using Sieve of Eratosthenes
    for (int i = 2; i*i <= N; i++) {

        // if i is prime, then mark multiples of i as nonprime
        // suffices to consider mutiples i, i+1, ..., N/i
        if (isPrime[i]) {
            for (int j = i; i*j <= N; j++) {
                isPrime[i*j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    // count primes
    int primes = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
        if (isPrime[i]) primes++;
    }
    System.out.println("The number of primes <= " + N + " is " + primes);
}
}
```

Comment: Use a data type with larger capacity like `long'. If even that does not suffice, then you can think about using `BigInt`.

Answer (score 0):

> however what I am struggling with, is what if I want the program to print out whether the number the user entered is a prime or not (simple yes or no).

Your current `isPrime` function seems to work, so just ask for a number and test it.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  System.out.println("Enter a number (is it prime): ");
  int num = scanner.nextInt();
  if (isPrime(num)) {
    System.out.printf("%d yes%n", num);
  } else {
    System.out.printf("%d no%n", num);        
  }
}
```

Or with a ternary,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  System.out.println("Enter a number (is it prime): ");
  int num = scanner.nextInt();
  System.out.printf("%d %s%n", num, isPrime(num) ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

**Edit** Based on your comment, move your print up sequence to a method

```
public static void primesUpTo(int num) {
  System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to " + num + " are: ");
  for (int number = 2; number <= num; number++) {
    if (isPrime(number)) {
      System.out.println(number);
    }
  }
}
```

Then

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
  System.out.println("Enter a number (is it prime): ");
  int num = scanner.nextInt();
  if (num > 50) {
    System.out.printf("%d %s%n", num, isPrime(num) ? "yes" : "no");
  } else {
    primesUpTo(num); // <-- call the method above.
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but where do I add if statement that does the following: if the number entered is below 50, then the program prints out all the prime numbers up to the entered number. If the number the user entered is bigger than 50, it tells only whether the entered number is prime or not ( simply "It's a prime" or "No, it's not a prime"). Hope that made things clearer :p.

Comment: @arri Edited based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
  int j = 2;   //variable
      int result = 0; //variable
      int number = 0; //variable
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner object
      System.out.println("Please enter a number: "); //Instruction
      number = reader.nextInt(); //Get the number entered
      while (j <= number / 2) //start loop, during loop j will become each number between 2 and 
      {                             //the entered number divided by 2
          if (number % j == 0) //If their is no remainder from your number divided by j...
      {
         result = 1;  //Then result is set to 1 as the number divides equally by another number, hergo
    }                //it is not a prime number
    j++;  //Increment j to the next number to test against the number you entered
  }
  if (result == 1)  //check the result from the loop
  {
   System.out.println("Number: " + number + " is Not Prime."); //If result 1 then a prime     
}
  else
 {
  System.out.println("Number: " + number + " is Prime. "); //If result is not 1 it's not a prime
 }
```

this is more efficient way tough:-

```
 public boolean isPrime(int  n) {
        // fast even test.
        if(n > 2 && (n & 1) == 0)
           return false;
        // only odd factors need to be tested up to n^0.5
        for(int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2)
            if (n % i == 0) 
                return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question right:

- If user enteres number lesser than or equal to 50, then print all primes that are lesser than that number.
- Otherwise, just write if inputted number is a prime.

With already existing `isPrime()` method:

```
int num = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();

if (num <= 50) {
    System.out.println("Prime numbers from 1 to " + num + " are: ");

    for (int number = 2; number <= num; number++) {
        if (isPrime(number)) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
} else { //num > 50
    if(isPrime(num)) {
        System.out.println(num + " is prime.");
    } else {
        System.out.println(num + " isn't prime.");
    }
}
```